# How to count rows in text files and store them in a single file?

Tags: powershell

Hello I use this code below to count lines in each text file in a directory and then store that information in a single file. Problem is that output file store a full path to each text file:
output example:

```
c:\Text folder\file1.txt,14                  
c:\Text folder\file2.txt,20          
c:\Text folder\file3.txt,25
```

I need output to be like this:

```
file1,14   
file2,20   
file3,25
```

Thank you for help. This is my code:

```
Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem -re -in $include -ex $exclude $path |
Foreach-Object { Write-Host "Counting $_.FullName"                 
$fileStats = Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object -line
$linesInFile = $fileStats.Lines
"$_,$linesInFile" } | Out-File $outputFile -encoding "UTF8"
Write-Host "Complete"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Basename` property of the `FileInfo`-objects.

```
"$($_.BaseName),$linesInFile"
```

You can simplify the line count by doing:

```
$linesInFile = @(Get-Content -Path $_.Fullname).Count
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It if working OK, but what you mean by "simplify the line count". Would it run much faster? Could you suggest some improvement what would speed up running my code? I have thousands of text files in  a folder and it take some time to count lines in all files.

Comment: Yes it will be faster (unless your files are 100Mb+). Less cmdlets required used = less overhead = better performance. Using a streamreader would be even faster, but optimization isn't part of this question. It was just a comment so you could skip the `measure-object` cmdlet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `BaseName` property, compare with full `Get-ChildItem|Get-Member`

```
#Parameters:
# path - the path containing the code files
# outputFile - fully qualified path of the file 
# include (Optional) - file mask(s) to include in the count (deafults to *.*)
# exclude (Optional) - file mask(s) to exclude in the count (defaults to none)
# Example (count lines in target path including *.cs but excluding *.designer.cs)
# .\countLOC.ps1 -path "C:\code\MyProject" -outputFile "C:\code\loc.csv" -include "*.cs" -exclude "*.designer.cs"
param(  [string]$path=".",                            # debug current directory if omitted
        [string]$outputFile="$env:TEMP\37514786.txt", # debug some file
        [string]$include = "*.*", 
        [string]$exclude = "")

Clear-Host
Get-ChildItem  -re -in $include -ex $exclude $path |
Foreach-Object { 
    Write-Host "Counting $_.FullName"                 
    $fileStats = Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object -line
    $linesInFile = $fileStats.Lines
    "$($_.BaseName),$linesInFile" 
               } | Out-File $outputFile -encoding "UTF8"
Write-Host "Complete"
# debug Get-Content $outputFile | Measure-Object -line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REM VBS
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Const ForReading = 1
Dim f, colFiles, objFile
Dim tFolder, tFile
Dim lineToCopy, readFile, strData, strTextFile, arrLines, LineCount

REM This is the Target Folder and File 
Set tFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\target")
Set tFile = tFolder.CreateTextFile("Header_Count1.log", True)

REM This is the Source Folder to count records
Set f = fso.GetFolder("S:\source")
Set colFiles = f.Files
For Each objFile In colFiles

    REM passage below finds all .txt files in selected folder
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "txt" Then
        strData = fso.OpenTextFile(objFile, ForReading).ReadAll
        arrLines = Split(strData, vbCrLf)

        REM passage subracts 1 from the .txt file count if there is a header record
        LineCount = UBound(arrLines) - 1
        tFile.WriteLine "FileName   "& objFile.Name & " RecordCount " & LineCount
    End If
Next

REM This pops up once the script is complete
Wscript.Echo "File Count Read of " & f &" Complete"
Set fso = Nothing
```